# Mysql function for zip radius crawls on our production server, but is fine on local and staging servers

Tags: mysql

Production is 5.7.27 and local is 5.7.35 - hopefully that is not the issue.

Problem involves getting a list of IDs within a zip code and radius.

function "get_zip_point" takes the zip and returns long and lat:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE _point POINT;
     SELECT POINT(zd_long, zd_lat) INTO _point
     FROM zipdata
     WHERE zd_zip = LEFT(_zip, 5);
  RETURN _point;
END
```

This is then sent into function distance_between:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE _degree FLOAT DEFAULT pi()/180;
  DECLARE _lat_1   FLOAT DEFAULT st_x(_point_1) * _degree;
  DECLARE _lng_1   FLOAT DEFAULT st_y(_point_1) * _degree;
  DECLARE _lat_2   FLOAT DEFAULT st_x(_point_2) * _degree;
  DECLARE _lng_2   FLOAT DEFAULT st_y(_point_2) * _degree;
  DECLARE _lat_d   FLOAT DEFAULT _lat_2 - _lat_1;
  DECLARE _lng_d   FLOAT DEFAULT _lng_2 - _lng_1;
  DECLARE _ans     FLOAT;

  SET _ans = POWER(SIN(_lat_d / 2), 2) + COS(_lat_1) * COS(_lat_2) * POWER(SIN(_lng_d / 2), 2);
  SET _ans = 2 * ASIN(SQRT(_ans));

  RETURN _ans * 3956;
END
```

On my local desktop I can run that and pull up thousands of correct results in 1-2 seconds based on a table of IDs and zips of close to a million rows.

On production, it'll run forever and eventually timeout.

Comment: can you not update your production server to the last version?

Comment: was hoping to avoid that - I've had bad luck upgrading server versions before, though not sure if that was just much earlier versions or not

Comment: Performance question need a lot more information see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions